# OneMap Rest API

Tags: android

I'm trying to develop an Android mobile application using OneMap. http://www.onemap.sg/API/Help/
I'm to make use of the Rest API but I have no idea how to start off, which is to first get the token. 
Could anyone help me with this?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.onemap.sg/API/Help/TokenApi.aspx ?

Says that you need an accessKey, "AccessKEY provided during registration."

Example1 : Specify AccessKEY to get the short live token (24 hours). The response is in JSON format.

http://www.onemap.sg/API/services.svc/getToken?accessKEY=qo/s2TnSUmfLz+32CvLC4RMVkzEFYjxqyti1KhByvEacEdMWBpCuSSQ+IFRT84QjGPBCuz/cBom8PfSm3GjEsGc8PkdEEOEr

JSON Response (copy above URL and Try here)

{GetToken:[{"NewToken":"3UE9oKyubVzDh/mXFqqsGOtdBgCjdIB17nd99i7yLWVn3XSP+DVcrkuX"}]}

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for your reply. I have the accesskey already. The problem is that I don't know how to get the token even when the site has shown example.
Do I have to code? I possible, could you help me with the Static Map API? Sorry, really need help on this.